# How to write logfile in C

Tags: c, logging

I want to write logfile in C program. I also want it to add new logfile with tempstamp on daily basis.

Do you an idea, or is there a libary?

Comment: what do you mean by "log file"? it is just a file, right? and you want to append newlogfile to it? use the append flag in fopen...! or do you mean you need to add to both the timestamp? (timestamp == tempstamp?)... clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

There are logging libraries for C, for example [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: but i want just header file not install and graph install :-(

Comment: if you want to use an external library you need to install it! Just header files won't work you need the library too. And if you meant graphviz and not graph, you don't need to install it, unless you want to build the documentation with doxygen

Comment: think you but no way with fopen fclose fwrite system for time !!

Comment: This is probably one of the best ways to go about logging - using an external, proven, library - because they generally have what you'd expect to eventually want in a logging class. I've written many loggers, but now, there's just no damn point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/). 
Here is simple logfile creation written in C.

```
/*Write your won logfile in c.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOG(X, Y) fprintf (fp, #X ": Time:%s, File:%s(%d) " #Y  "\n", __TIMESTAMP__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

int main(int args, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp= fopen("logfile.txt", "w"); //("c:\\temp\\logfile.txt")

    LOG(INFO, "File open success.");
    LOG(WARN, "File path missing.");
    LOG(ERROR, "File close faild.");

    fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The use of `fprintf()` makes this unsafe for multithreaded processes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks! +1 for you noticed perfect!  Will learn to make it safe. Could u suggest me anything?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to write the output of your program into a log file? 
This is done when you are writing big applications and you need to analyse the logs to know the exact behaviour of the software. 
In this case you may want to redirect the output to a log file and read and analyse it later.
Incase you dont want to use any of the standard logging library, you may have to write a daemon to capture the output and create a log file.

I am quoting assuming you want to create a file log utility.